# SSH command from C# client redirecting files

Tags: c#, redirect, ssh, sharpssh

The original Unix implementation simply did something like this:

```
ssh [batchname] < [inputfilename] > [outputfilename]
```

I need to be able to do the same thing from a windows machine running an application written in C#.  I've tried using SharpSsh, which includes input and output streams, but they don't seem to work.

How can I pipe the input and output files/streams using SharpSsh (or any other .Net library)?

Comment: "It doesn't work" is too broad. Did you try to debug the code? What problems did you have?

Comment: It depends on what I tried to do.  In general, the behavior was like the streams never connected with the server.  I don't know if the input stream ever got information to the server, but the output stream was always either closed and unreadable or a read would hang for far longer than it should have (should take a second or two, waited for minutes).

Comment: To be more explicit, if I use SshExec.RunCommand and simply add the input file contents to the command string (separating with a space or a newline), the RunCommand call doesn't return.  If I use SshShell and write out the command and input file, the output stream is not available or remains empty.

Comment: Can you please post a code snippet how you figured it out?
I am facing the same issue actually :( Need your help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.  Either the application running or SSH itself expects a ctrl-d to signal the end of the input.  At that point, the output stream can be read without hanging.

Comment: FYI: You can accept your own answer to let others know that it exists.